# Building a scaleable external api for Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I've just started at a company that currently uses Odoo but is facing issues with regards to usability of the user-interface.We want to continue to use Odoo for trained managers, but build a suite of external "micro-apps" in React JS that allow end-users to have a simple, modern, responsive interface that is tailored to their specific task.

The React apps will need to leverage Odoo's data via an API that does not exist yet, but that will need to be scalable and robust with features you'd expect in a production grade API, eg type validation, http error handling, testing, etc

I've never worked with Odoo before, so I'd really appreciate input, experience sharing on best practices for this kind of thing.

A few of the options that I've seen out there:

- Leverage an external server [like FASTAPI using odoo.api.Environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFpezjMGdNc)
- Native Odoo JSON-RPC API
- Native Odoo XML-RPC API
- utilize the [base_rest framework](https://github.com/OCA/rest-framework)

Any thoughts, expertise, resources, links would be much appreciated.

Note: I've cross-posted this from [r/Odoo](https://www.reddit.com/r/Odoo/comments/15h9tzm/externalfacing_api_react_apps/) since I'm not sure where the community is most active. Feel free to answer in either spot and I'll summarize takeaways in both threads.

Googling and searching Odoo documentation / Odoo Experience talks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting but IMO it's better to not mix apples and oranges here. The easiest thing should be create those mini-apps directly in Odoo.

But if you need specific mini-app not related to Odoo it's better to build it completely outside Odoo.

I have an strong background on Odoo and I'm doing pretty much the same with some other apps that I'm building with ReactJS not integrated with Odoo at all and going all the way down with FastAPI and others servers instead of Odoo

Comment: Yeah, I'm considering the direct integration, but there's a chance we'd like to gradually move away from Odoo. So I'm leaning towards keeping the mini-apps separate. When you say "it's better to build it completely outside Odoo" are you referring to the REST API? Can you provide some details on your setup @aekis.dev?

Comment: Completely outside of Odoo I mean using other servers like FastAPI with Starlette with PonyORM talking to MariaDB or MySQL or PostgreSQL, with ReactJS with MaterialUI in the frontend, and maybe also TailwindCSS

Comment: Also since I'm hitting some DevOps scenarios also with async distributed processing of data I'm doing some stuffs with Saltstack and Tornado

Comment: My recommendation it's to use Odoo completely or go into another direction with any other Python Web Stack. Mixin it's not a good idea since you will need to maintain 2 or more applications in order to get the same. Pretty much the models and actions that you put into Odoo modules will need a counterpart views, menus, actions for you to manage it from Odoo an also the design of the modules will be based into Odoo way of doing things and you will need to adapt everything you develop outside to match Odoo. it's like running a car with 2 different size of wheels